# FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage is not working

Tags: asp.net

I am working on a LoginPage.Everything related to database or C# code is working fine but after successul login I am unable to redirect to Home.aspx,am I missing Something? Pls help.
**Code:**

**Web.Config:**

```
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="*"/>

</authorization>
```

**C# Code:**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string source = "server=localhost\\sqlexpress;Database=LogInDB;Trusted_Connection=True";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(source);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("proc_LogIn", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TextBox1.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text;
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(TextBox1.Text, false);
                    }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Invalid credentials");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 5):

It should be `<deny users="?"/>`

```
* means all 
? means unauthenticated
```

Comment: I have one question ,why do we need to use FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage method ? why Response.Redirect() doesnt work.?

Comment: Well the RedirectFromLoginPage does more than just redirect. It creates a cookie as well as redirecting you to your previous page (where you clicked on the login button). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka5ffkce.aspx for more details.

Answer (score 1):

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms 
        loginUrl="login.aspx" 
        defaultUrl="home.aspx" 
        slidingExpiration="true" 
        timeout="20" name=".Auth" 
        protection="All">
    </forms>
</authentication>
```

Apart from doing the setting mentioned by Mladen, you'll have to do these settings in your web.config before calling that method.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, despite having code from both provided answers in my web.config, `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` was navigating back to `loginUrl`.

It seems to be a known issue described in these two threads ([1](https://forums.asp.net/t/1200058.aspx?%20FormsAuthentication%20RedirectFromLoginPage%20Problem), [2](https://forums.asp.net/t/1155607.aspx?FormsAuthentication%20RedirectFromLoginPage%20doesn%20t%20work)). As adviced there, using a combination of authCookie and redirect worked for me.

**VB.NET code:**

```vb
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtUsername.Value, False)
    Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.DefaultUrl, False)
```